# Fetching data from polymorphic relation in laravel

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, one-to-many

i have three tables that has poly morphic relationship,
maintenance:
-id
-stock_SNW_issue_id

Obsolescence:
-id
-stock_SNW_issue_id

Staff_performance
-id
-performance_id
-performance_type

I want to get id from maintenance table where stock_SNW_issue_id = $issueId, and check whether that id exists on the staff_performance table or not.

This is my function inside controller:

```
public function isIssueAssigned($issueId)
    {
        $bio_id = bio_md_maintenance_dealer::where('stock_SNW_issue_id', $issueId)->value('id');

        $isAssigned = Staff_Performances::whereHas('performance', function ($subQuery) use ($bio_id) {
            $subQuery->where('performance_id', $bio_id)
                ->where('performance_type', 'App\Models\Hospitals\MaintenanceReport\bio_md_maintenance_dealer');
        })->exists();

        return response()->json(['isAssigned' => $isAssigned]);
    }
```

this is my staff_performance model:

```
public function performance()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

this is maintenance model:

```
public function staffPerformances()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Staff_Performances::class, 'performance');
    }
```

this is obsolescence model:

```
public function staffPerformances()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Staff_Performances::class, 'performance');
    }
```

I got two issues:
1- This code runs infinitively
2- gives performance_id column not found error.

Comment: hey @Newbie upvote and right tic if you got the satisfy with my answer

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop issue in your code seems to be due to the way you're using morph relationships and eager loading. Also, the "column not found" error is likely because the `Staff_Performances` model doesn't have a column named `performance_id`. Instead, it's using polymorphic relations. Here's how you can refactor your code to address both issues:

First, ensure that your `Staff_Performances` migration has the necessary columns for polymorphic relations, typically `performance_id`, `performance_type`, and other relevant columns.

Assuming your `Staff_Performances` model is correctly set up with morphTo relations, here's how you can refactor your `isIssueAssigned` function:

```php
use App\Models\Staff_Performances;
use App\Models\Hospitals\MaintenanceReport\bio_md_maintenance_dealer;

public function isIssueAssigned($issueId)
{
    // Get the maintenance record ID based on the issue ID
    $maintenanceId = bio_md_maintenance_dealer::where('stock_SNW_issue_id', $issueId)->value('id');

    // Check if the maintenance record is assigned in staff performance
    $isAssigned = Staff_Performances::where('performance_id', $maintenanceId)
        ->where('performance_type', 'App\Models\Hospitals\MaintenanceReport\bio_md_maintenance_dealer')
        ->exists();

    return response()->json(['isAssigned' => $isAssigned]);
}
```

Ensure that you have imported the necessary models at the top of your controller.

This refactored code directly queries the `Staff_Performances` table for the existence of a record where the `performance_id` matches the maintenance record ID and the `performance_type` matches the type of the maintenance record. This should avoid the infinite loop issue and resolve the "column not found" error.

Remember to adjust the namespaces and class names as per your actual application structure.